# Use multiple sampler2D over one input texture in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Now I have a noise texture generated by this website: https://aeroson.github.io/rgba-noise-image-generator/. I want to use 4 uniform samplers in my computing shader to get 4 random rgba values from a **single** noise texture. My computing shader source codes look like:

```
#version 430 core

layout (local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

uniform sampler2D noise_r0;
uniform sampler2D noise_i0;
uniform sampler2D noise_r1;
uniform sampler2D noise_i1;

layout (binding = 0, rgba32f) writeonly uniform image2D tilde_h0k;

layout (binding = 1, rgba32f) writeonly uniform image2D tilde_h0minusk;

uniform int N = 256; 

....

// Box-Muller algorithm
vec2 texCoord = vec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy) / float(N); // Here every invocation refers to a pixel of output image 
float noise00 = clamp(texture(noise_r0, texCoord).r, 0.001, 1.0);
float noise01 = clamp(texture(noise_i0, texCoord).r, 0.001, 1.0);
float noise02 = clamp(texture(noise_r1, texCoord).r, 0.001, 1.0);
float noise03 = clamp(texture(noise_i1, texCoord).r, 0.001, 1.0);

....
```

and in the main program, I use this code to upload my downloaded noise texture to the computing shader:

```
unsigned int tex_noise;
glGenTextures(1, &tex_noise);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_noise);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
int w_noise, h_noise, nrChannels;
unsigned char* data = stbi_load("noise.png", &w_noise, &h_noise, &nrChannels, 0);
if (data) {
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w_noise, h_noise, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
else std::cout << "Failed to load noise texture." << std::endl;
stbi_image_free(data);
....
....
```

My question is: Can I set up those sampler2D's in computing shader using this code?

```
glUseProgram(computeProgram);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(computeProgram, "noise_r0"), 1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(computeProgram, "noise_i0"), 2);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(computeProgram, "noise_r1"), 3);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(computeProgram, "noise_i1"), 4);
```

If it is wrong, what should I do to set up those sampler2D's, and make sure that the random rgba values I get from those sampler2D's are not the same? (cause if they are the same, the Box-Muller algorithm won't work).
Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the uniform is `ìmage2D`, not `sampler2D`. To load and store an image, you must bind the texture to an image unit using [`glBindImageTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindImageTexture.xhtml). See [Image Load Store](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store). e.g.:

```cpp
glBindImageTexture(1, tex_noise, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
```

---

If you want to bind a texture to a texture unit you need to select active texture unit with [`glActiveTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glActiveTexture.xhtml) and then bind the texture with [`glBindTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindTexture.xhtml):

```cpp
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_object);
```

You can access this texture in the shader with a uniform of type `sampler2D` and the `texture*` functions:

```c
layout(binding = 1) uniform sampler2D myTextue;
```

---

If you want to bind a texture to a image unit, you have to use [`glBindImageTexture`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindImageTexture.xhtml):

```cpp
glBindImageTexture(1, texture_object, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_RGBA32F);
```

You can access this texture in the shader with a uniform of type `iamge2D` and and the `image*` functions:

```c
layout (binding = 1, rgba32f) writeonly uniform image2D myImage;
```

Comment: In fact I don't want to render this noise texture, I just want to use the rgba data within it to do stuffs in computing shader. BTW, I'm not sure I understand why `sampler2D` doesn't work.

Comment: @Scanners I don't understand your question. The type of the uniform is `image2D` and you access the texture with `imageStore`. You cannot write to a `sampler2D`, there isn't even a glsl function for it.

Comment: But isn't `sampler2D` bind to a texture unit? Why we cannot use it to access a texture? I'm confused :(

Comment: @Scanners `sampler2D` can only be accessed with the `texture` function, but not with `imageStore` and `imageLoad`. Basically you are asking why you cannot an object of type `B` with `Foo(A a)` and why you have to use `Bar(B b)`. `sampler2D` and `image2D` are different types. `glBindImageTexture` binds `image2D`. `glBindTexture` binds `sampler2D`.